# Link an iOS 5 and an iOS 8 device in Clash of Clans

Tags: technical-issues, clash-of-clans

I have been playing on an iOS 8 device and I got another iOS 5 device (iPad first generation). I have been backing up the game on the iOS 8 device using Game Center. I tried to restore that game to the new (iOS 5 device) but it won't work, it gives me this error:

> "Switching to this account is not supported below iOS version 7. To switch to this account please update your iOS version."

It seems SuperCell isn't supporting transfer of games started on iOS after 7 to devices under 7:

http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/383594-Hay-Day-iOS-Players-Important-Info

Then I tried linking using Facebook but that didn't work either. It's just offering to replace the Facebook backup with with the village that currently on the device. It never offers to restore from Facebook. Is there a way to do that?

Is there a way to link accounts on iOS 8 and iOS 5 devices?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck contacting SuperCell support for this.

Comment: There does not appear to currently be a way

Answer (score 1):

That happened to my friend, the game is not the same on devices lower than IOS 7. hope 
this helped